# -INTELLIJ IDEA 2020.3- Cannot connect to demostore.gatling.io

Tags: proxy, gatling

I am trying to execute a Gatling scenario to the https://demostore.gatling.io website, after register it through Chrome HAR export (inside my dev environment).

Import and everything goes smoothly, but when I run the scenario I receive the following error:

```
i.n.c.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: demostore.gatling.io/54.147.169.32:80
```

I then tried to set up the IntelliJ proxy from Settings → System Settings → HTTP Proxy, setting it to *Manually* and providing the correct proxy configuration → `Test Connection` vs `http://demostore.gatling.io` and the IDE returns *Connection Succesful*.

Currently, my environment is as follow:

- Intellij IDEA 2020.3
- Gatling 3.5.1
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64 bit (on VirtualBox)
- I am behind a VPN with proxy (need this since Maven is configured to use the internal Nexus repo)

Comment: This question was answered by @StéphaneLANDELLE, but the thread was deleted after editing something in the above question.
Stéphane was pointing me correctly to: [Proxy parameters](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol/#proxy-parameters) in the official Gatling documentation and after setting: 

`http.proxy(Proxy("<URL>", <PORT>).credentials("<user>", "<pwd>"))`

everything started working as expected.

Comment: Please add that as an answer.

Comment: @double-beep waiting to understand if the answer that was deleted can be restored. If none, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by @StéphaneLANDELLE, but the thread was deleted after editing something in the above question.

Stéphane was pointing me correctly to: [Proxy parameters](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol/#proxy-parameters) in the official Gatling documentation and after setting:

```
http.proxy(Proxy("<URL>", <PORT>).credentials("<user>", "<pwd>"))
```

everything started working as expected.

Comment: My answer was deleted because some modos wanted me to copy-paste the official documentation here instead of providing a link, under the false pretence that links might break some day. Doesn't copy-pasted documentation rot as well?

Comment: Glad you could get the answer before they deleted it and it helped. I'm not here for the points...

Comment: Sorry for that Stéphane.. anyway It helped a lot (in that page there were other useful hints).